# Mock.Of<foo> Setting return for Method Calls With Parameters

Tags: c#, linq, moq

Trying to figure out how to set up a Method that has parameters using Linq to Mock

```
Mock.Of<foo>(f=> f.Method(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()) ==
        Func<DateTime,DateTime,List<DateTime> = (date1,date2){ /*stuff*/ });
```

something like that, have tried a few variations and been digging around the web. I'm confidant I have done this before but for the life of me can't find what im missing.

Comment: This wouldn't even compile...

Comment: Right, it's an example of why I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Moq, assuming your interface is like this:

```
interface foo 
{ 
    List<DateTime> Method(DateTime date1, DateTime date2); 
}
```

The syntax I think you're looking for to setup the mock is

```
var bar = new Mock<foo>();
bar.Setup(f => f.Method(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
   .Returns<DateTime,DateTime>((date1, date2) => new List<DateTime> { date1, date2 });
```

---

**Edit**

After searching around, I [found this](http://www.daedtech.com/mock-of-and-mock-get-in-moq) which I think other syntax which I think is what you are looking for:

```
var bar = Mock.Of<foo>();
Mock.Get(bar).Setup(f => f.Method(It.IsAny<DateTime>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
   .Returns<DateTime,DateTime>((date1, date2) => new List<DateTime> { date1, date2 });
```

Comment: I'm aware of this approach but prefer the. Of<foo> syntax. I know there is a way and that once done this before just can't find it.... Thanks for the reply though

Comment: @workabyte Check my edit. I think that's the syntax you're looking for.

Comment: I am almost positive there is a way to set it up directly in the .Of<>()
This does work to but would really like to be able to just wire it all up in one call just beauce......Ill give it another day or two to see if someone has the answer and if not ill mark this as the answer because you are right and they do work just trying to do it a little differently.

Answer (score 0):

This will set up your Mock to return `expectedResult` if your method is called with parameters `date1 and date2`.

```
var bar = Mock.Of<foo>(f => f.Method(date1, date2) == expectedResult);
```

I'm still trying to figure out if there is a way to set it so that the Mocked method returns it's own input, but haven't yet with the new `.Of` method.

Comment: when using `.Of<>` and want to setup the return it looks like you have to use `Mock.Get(bar).Setup...` see in answer above

Comment: You can, but you don't have to., I've used the pattern like in mine to set up methods as well.